# Mocking const values for testing

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to unit test an HTTP API written in C++:

```
void getLogNames(Request & req, Response & res) 
{
    vector<string> files = getFilesInDirectory(LOG_LOCATION, ".log", false);
    json response(files);
    res.send(response);
}
```

The problem is that `LOG_LOCATION` is included from `common.h` and is `const`, and can't be changed by my testing code:

```
const std::string LOG_LOCATION = "/var/log"
```

I've tried doing this at the top of the file:

```
#ifdef UNIT_TEST
#include <common_mock.h>
#else
#include <common.h>
#endif
```

However, `common.h` is included in some shared libraries that are being linked in, and I would have to add `UNIT_TEST` hooks to all those files and rebuild the shared libraries as well, which I would rather avoid...

Is there an easier way I could be doing this, some `#define` tricks or something?

Comment: `#define LOG_LOCATION std::string{"/some/other/location"}`?

Comment: @nwp This would still need to go in a `UNIT_TEST` mock header in the source file, correct?

Comment: It seems you want to test `getLogNames`: provide a mock implementation of `getFilesInDirectory()` and link that instead for the test.

Comment: @DietmarKühl I think this is what I want to do. I'm testing too many things at once. `getFilesInDirectory` has its own unit test, so I think mocking that entire function is the way to go here. If you write this as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can try to const_cast a pointer to your LOG_LOCATION but it's dirty and unreliable solution and may cause seg fault. For example:

*original_file.h*

```
#include <iostream>

const std::string LOG_LOCATION = "/var/log";

int func() {
    std::cout << LOG_LOCATION << std::endl;
}
```

*unit_test.cpp*

```
#include "test.h"

void someUnitTest() {
    const std::string* cs = &LOG_LOCATION;

    std::string* s = const_cast<std::string*>(cs);
    *s = "NEW_VALUE";

    std::cout << *s;
}

int main() {
    someUnitTest();
}
```

This code may work in some cases (i.e. this successfully compiled and worked in GCC but only for class object type - it crashes with buildin type like int) but is may change with different compilers, platforms, or optimization levels.

**The recommended way** is to redesign your application and use dependency injections, for example wrap your function calls in a class and put this location as a settable member.

Answer (score 0):

Why don’t you change your class to receive the log location in its constructor? By hardcoding it (macros are eqivalent to hardcoding from the testing point of view) you’re purposely making your class less testable.

Comment: What do you mean "my class"? This is a callback function for an HTTP API that a user might call from a browser.